# Clicking on a link and visiting it using app doesn't mark it as visited in browser

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app, google-chrome, browsers

Searching in Google and visiting links which open in the app doesn't mark those links as visited when you return back from app to search results in browser.

Comment: How can the SE server control how your browser colors links?  The same thing happens if you use more than one browser.

Comment: @MonicaCellio This is not quite the same as two browsers. My understanding is that the OP clicks on links to SE posts in a browser, but those links are (naturally) set to open in the app. The browser could still mark them as visited, but apparently it does not want to. [I agree SE probably can't do anything about it.]

Comment: Oh, you mean the search results page from which he launched the app?  Ok, missed that.  (When a link from search results launches some other app, like YouTube, the PDF reader, etc, do *those* get marked as visited in the browser?)

Comment: Yes, those get marked.

Comment: And the reason to downvote is...?

Comment: @abatishchev this is an impossible feature request, so quite pointless hence the downvotes. (probably)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: 
 
Inability to implement doesn't make the request bad so it doesn't deserve downvotes. Because it's actually good!

Answer (score 4):

This is probably in the hands of the browser and out of the hands of the SE team.

The browser has not accessed that page before. It is not in the browser's history. Therefore, as far as the browser cares, that link has not been visited by it.

You sure did click on it, but the browser didn't handle it and as far as it's aware you've never been to that page in your life.

Comment: But (I can be wrong here) it's used to work as I expect: was marking links as visited. Can it be?

Comment: @abatishchev Maybe your browser changed how it handles visited links.